# iostat for sockets listening on localhost

Tags: linux, performance, system-administration

I've got a process listening on localhost and another process writing to it. Obviously, they're both on the same machine. Are there any tools out the for figuring out what the throughput is between those two processes?

iostat et. al. won't fly because it's not actual I/O AFAIK.